# Remove email attachments from iPhone

Tags: iphone, email, disk-space, attachments

After having clicked on an attachment in an email to download and see/read it... is there a way to remove it again? I don't want to delete the email or the attachment from the email server, I just don't want it to take up space on the iPhone.

And also, is there a way to remove all downloaded attachments, so I don't have to go through each email and find which I have downloaded earlier?

Answer (score 1):

The attachments will not remain on the phone past the point that the email itself is in the default number downloaded by Mail (on my iPhone it's 50 most recent messages). Once the message falls out of that, and/or is deleted, its attachments should be removed from the phone memory.

The other way to be entirely sure they are gone is to disable 'Mail' in settings for the account you are using, wait a couple of seconds (let it do its thing) and re-enable. This will purge everything related to that mail account and let you redownload just the messages. If you download a lot of attachments versus the amount of mail you receive, it might be worth doing this on a weekly-or-so basis.

Comment: I don't think disabling "Mail" in settings deletes the attachments off of your phone. I tried it, went to my mailbox, the messages were all gone. Then re-enabled mail and went back to my mailbox. Messages with attachments in both (the inbox and sent folders) did not require me to re-download the attachments I had previously downloaded.

Answer (score -2):

This is same my problem which I had it.I format my phone completely to solve the memory problem. My cell phone was having more than 10 gigabytes of file attachments.